# Writing a Raytracer, and perspective viewing system not displaying properly?

Tags: java, raytracing, perspectivecamera

In a ray tracer I'm writing I've just tried to implement a proper perspective viewing system, however something seems to be wrong with it and I can't seem to figure out what is happening.

For example with a scene with three spheres, green, red and blue at **(-150.0,0.0,0.0)**, **(0.0,0.0,0.0)** and **(150.0,0.0,0.0)** respectively and a camera at **(0.0,0.0,-600.0)**, pointed at the centre sphere I get this image:

[image]

Which seems about right.

If I move the camera to **(0.0, 600.0,-600.0)**, still pointed at the centre sphere, I would expect to get a similar image since I haven't moved left or right. However this is what is rendered:

[image]
Which doesn't make any sense to me.

This is my perspective porjector class:

```
public class PerspectiveProjector extends Projector{

public Point3D camera;
public Point3D sceneLocation;
public double distance;
public Vector3D u, v, w;

public PerspectiveProjector(Point3D camera, Point3D sceneLocation, double FOV){
    this.camera = new Point3D(camera);
    this.sceneLocation = new Point3D(sceneLocation);
    this.distance = RayTracer.world.viewPlane.height/2/Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV));   

    uvw();
}

private void uvw() {

    w = camera.subtractVector(sceneLocation);
    w.normalise();

    //prob
    u = new Vector3D(0.00424,1.0,0.00764).cross(w);
    u.normalise();

    v = w.cross(u);
    v.normalise();  
}


public Ray createRay(Point2D point) {

    Ray ray = new Ray(new Point3D(camera), u.multiply(point.x).add(v.multiply(point.y).subtract(w.multiply(distance))));

    ray.direction.normalise();

    return ray;
}


}
```

If you would like to see any more of my code please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're doing to get your u value, so here's how I would solve that problem.

In order to make the X coordinate of the image be horizontal, the u vector needs to lie in the XY plane, so the z coordinate must be zero. To keep the X coordinate perpendicular to the direction the camera direction, which, in your code, is w, their dot product must be zero. A vector like this must have the coordinates:

u = Vector3D(w.y,-w.x,0) or

u = Vector3D(-w.y,w.x,0)

This works because the dot product of the two vectors must algebraically be zero.

(x,y,z)*(y,-x,0) = xy + -yx + 0z = xy - xy + 0 = 0; therefore, (y,-x,0) must be a point on the xy plane perpendicular to (x,y,z).

Replace that one line and tell me if it works

Comment: Whoops, I use C++, just throw in the `new` keyword before Vector3D